# Haskell Implement Unix "touch" command

Tags: unix, haskell, command-line

I'm trying to implement the [`touch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(Unix)) command from the unix command line, but it seems that my last line throws an exception: `** Exception: ~/.todo: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`

```
main = touch "~/.todo"

touch :: FilePath -> IO ()
touch name = do
  exists <- doesFileExist name
  unless exists $ appendFile name ""
```

If there is any OS specific behavior, I'm testing from macOS Sierra.

I feel as if this error is strange in that the documentation for [`openFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO.html) states that

> If the file does not exist and it is opened for output, it should be created as a new file.

Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

**Edit:** According to @chi, the `touch` command should always open the file, even if it already exists, because it will then update the file's last modified date.

```
touch :: FilePath -> IO ()
touch name = appendFile name ""
```

Comment: i successfully touched many files using this code. is it possible you have a weird cwd?

Comment: By the way, `touch` is often also used to update the timestamp of an existing file.

Comment: The exception is being thrown at `openFile`, but your code snippet doesn't include that. Could you update it to include that?

Comment: Also, to add emphasis on your quote: "If the file does not exist *and it is opened for output*, it should be created". Without seeing `openFile`, I would guess that maybe you're not opening it with the correct mode.

Comment: @ocharles `appendFile` calls `withFile`. In turn, `withFile` calls `openFile`, you can check the source here https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/System.IO.html#appendFile

Comment: @chi so, whether or not the file exists, it should be opened and saved? I will edit my question

Comment: @haoformayor This was something that confused me about the documentation, are the `FilePath`s absolute location, relative location, or both? Can I use "~/foo.bar"?

Comment: The `FilePath` is the same as the OS's conception of a file path, so it can be absolute or relative, but you cannot use `~` to mean your home directory, since that is a shell feature. If the filename you are using is really just `file.dat`, the error only makes sense if your code has a current working directory that has been deleted or similar (what @haoformayor said).

Comment: @Zylviij I think so. I am unsure about how `touch` is implemented.

Comment: Please edit to include how you are calling `touch`  -  that is the code (or work flow) with the error, it is not in what you have shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use [`touchFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Files-ByteString.html#v:touchFile)** from the `unix` package (`System.Posix.Files.ByteString`).

---

`appendFile name ""` does **not** work like `touch`; `appendFile` is a no-op when the string to append is empty.

You can confirm this by running `stat` on the file before and after and comparing the modification times.

Comment: What makes the `ByteString` version better than the `FilePath` version https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.8.5.0/docs/System-Posix-Files.html#v:touchFile ?

Comment: @gwern It is generally more efficient and "modern" to use the `ByteString` representation of string types for OS APIs; `FilePath` is the Haskell `String` data type, which is `[Char]` (linked list of unicode characters) and considered by most Haskell users as a historical artifact. `Text` and `ByteString` are the recommended, compact data structures, similar to Python 3''s `str` and `bytes`. Of course, if you only have a single, short `FilePath`, there is no noticeable differnce, and the behaviour or touching the file is identical (both use the same underlying syscall).

Answer (score 2):

In the future please paste all the code you are using that creates the error.  This includes both the imports and the invocation.  In your case it seems you are running something with a shell expansion character:

```
*Main> touch "~/foobar"
*** Exception: ~/foobar: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

The `~` is typically expanded by a shell (there also exists a C library that can do that rewriting for you).  Most languages actually interpret that as a literal part of the path... but the `~` directory probably doesn't exist or that symbol might not even be valid depending on your platform.

Instead try a valid file path:

```
*Main> touch "/tmp/thisfile"
*Main>
Leaving GHCi.
% ls -l /tmp/thisfile
-rw-rw-r--. 1 theuser theuser 0 Feb  3 12:51 /tmp/thisfile
```

Comment: You are correct as to what my error was. I had suspected that this was the error but forgot to restart my ghci session.